# Get and change the unique Id of an Item (the shortest one)

Tags: podio

Is it possible to get and change an unique id of an item via Podio API? That one we enable on App Settings > Advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is now way for you to change an unique id of an item via the API (or by any other mean).